# How to create reordering functionality for rows in a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm currently refactoring a project that is using Python widgets along with JavaScript. It currently uses a table with a reorder feature that could use some major improvements. When using the "reorderRowDown" button, it works correctly the current row moves down and the previous and next row adjust accordingly.

However, on the "reorderRowUp" button the current row simply alternates back and forth between the current and previous row. (I hope I'm explaining this well, my apologies) It's very clunky moving the current row up the table.

I would like to achieve the functionality similar to "reorderRowDown" where when clicking "reorderRowUp" the current row moves up and the previous and next row adjust accordingly. In summary, I would like to know how to implement reordering of the rows in the table either up or down the correct way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Here are gifs posted below to better demonstrate the scenarios I'm referencing)

reorderRowDown Example:

https://media.giphy.com/media/8WHiGw57pPTK9Zdibk/giphy.gif

reorderRowUp Example:

https://media.giphy.com/media/Wp7x9GtYDX29cFLT6I/giphy.gif

Here's my code (please let me know if you require more)

PathContext.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = () => {
  window.reorderRowUp = function(ruleSetIdPriority) {
    let ruleSetId;

    ruleSetId = ruleSetIdPriority.split('-priority')[0];

    const row = document.getElementById(ruleSetId);
    const table = row.parentNode;
    const prevRow = row.previousElementSibling;

    table.insertBefore(row, prevRow);
  };

  window.reorderRowDown = function(ruleSetIdPriority) {
    let ruleSetId;

    ruleSetId = ruleSetIdPriority.split('-priority')[0];

    const row = document.getElementById(ruleSetId);
    const table = row.parentNode;
    const nextRow = row.nextElementSibling;

    table.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
  };
};
```

reorder_row_widget.html

```
<button class="reorder-btn" type="button" onclick=reorderRowUp("{{widget.name}}")>Up</button>
<button class="reorder-btn" type="button" onclick=reorderRowDown("{{widget.name}}")>Down</button>
<input id="{{ widget.name }}" type="hidden" name="{{ widget.name }}" value="{{ widget.value }}"></input>
```

Here's the html of the actual table row from the console in my browser

```
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr class="form-row row1 has_original dynamic-rule_set" id="rule_set-0">
            <td class="original">
            <p>
            Rule object (84)
            </p>
                <input type="hidden" name="rule_set-0-id" value="84" id="id_rule_set-0-id">
                <input type="hidden" name="rule_set-0-path_context" value="6" id="id_rule_set-0-path_context">
            </td>
            <td class="field-priority">   
                <button class="reorder-btn" type="button" onclick="reorderRowUp(&quot;rule_set-0-priority&quot;)">Up</button>
                <button class="reorder-btn" type="button" onclick="reorderRowDown(&quot;rule_set-0-priority&quot;)">Down</button>
                <input id="rule_set-0-priority" type="hidden" name="rule_set-0-priority" value="-301">
            </td>
            <td class="field-pattern"> 
                <input type="text" name="rule_set-0-pattern" value="^/$" id="id_rule_set-0-pattern"> 
            </td> 
            <td class="field-value">     
                <input class="tgl" id="rule_set-0-value" name="rule_set-0-value" type="checkbox" checked="">
                <label class="tgl-btn" for="rule_set-0-value"></label>
            </td> 
            <td class="field-experience">
                <select name="rule_set-0-experience" id="id_rule_set-0-experience">
                    <option value="">---------</option>
                    <option value="modal" selected="">Modal</option>
                    <option value="sticky_cta">Sticky CTA</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="delete"><input type="checkbox" name="rule_set-0-DELETE" id="id_rule_set-0-DELETE"></td>  
       </tr>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

admin.py (python code if needed)

```
class ReorderRowWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'admin/reorder_row_widget.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation I used to resolve my issue and create a better UI. I refactored the PathContext.js file.

```
  function replaceReorderFunction() {
    const reorderRowUp = window.reorderRowUp || function() {};
    const reorderRowDown = window.reorderRowDown || function() {};
    // when page gets rendered, django creates a hidden row with a special ruleSetId with id __prefix__
    // once 'add new row' is clicked, a real ruleSetId is given to the row
    // need to replace the reorder function of that row so that it uses the proper ruleSetId so the row can be reordered properly
    // should only need to happen once, on the first reordering after the row is added
    // therefore I assume that the row in question is always at the bottom of the table
    const tableWrapper = document.getElementById('rule_set-group');
    const tbody = tableWrapper.querySelector('tbody');
    const rowToUpdate = tbody.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
    const priorityField = rowToUpdate.getElementsByClassName('field-priority')[0];
    const buttons = priorityField.getElementsByTagName('button');
    buttons[0].onclick = () => {reorderRowUp(rowToUpdate.id);};
    buttons[1].onclick = () => {reorderRowDown(rowToUpdate.id);};
    return rowToUpdate.id;
  }

  window.reorderRowUp = function(ruleSetIdPriority) {
    let ruleSetId;
    // it's a new row, ruleSetId is not correct
    if (ruleSetIdPriority.match(/__prefix__/)) {
      // get the proper ruleSetId and replace existing onclick functions
      ruleSetId = replaceReorderFunction();
    } else {
      ruleSetId = ruleSetIdPriority.split('-priority')[0];
    }
    const row = document.getElementById(ruleSetId);
    const table = row.parentNode;
    const prevRow = row.previousElementSibling;
    if (!prevRow) {
      return;
    }
    table.insertBefore(row, prevRow);
    // swap priority values
    const prevPriorityValue = getPriorityValueFromRow(prevRow);
    const curPriorityValue = getPriorityValueFromRow(row);
    setPriorityValueOfRow(row, prevPriorityValue);
    setPriorityValueOfRow(prevRow, curPriorityValue);
  };

  window.reorderRowDown = function(ruleSetIdPriority) {
    let ruleSetId;
    // it's a new row, ruleSetId is not correct
    if (ruleSetIdPriority.match(/__prefix__/)) {
      ruleSetId = replaceReorderFunction();
    } else {
      ruleSetId = ruleSetIdPriority.split('-priority')[0];
    }
    const row = document.getElementById(ruleSetId);
    const table = row.parentNode;
    const nextRow = row.nextElementSibling;
    if (!nextRow || nextRow.className === 'add-row' || nextRow.id.includes('empty')) {
      return;
    }
    table.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
    // swap priority values
    const nextPriorityValue = getPriorityValueFromRow(nextRow);
    const curPriorityValue = getPriorityValueFromRow(row);
    setPriorityValueOfRow(row, nextPriorityValue);
    setPriorityValueOfRow(nextRow, curPriorityValue);
  };
```